# Why isn't this ternary expression working?

Tags: java

I'm quite new to Java and encountered this question.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> findex = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> lindex = new HashMap<>();
int current = 7, i = 3;
if (findex.get(current)==null) findex.put(current, i);
else lindex.put(current, i);
```

The if-else statement is working perfectly fine. However, the IDE gave me "not a statement" error when I do shorten if-else statement like this:

```
findex.get(current)==null ? findex.put(current, i) : lindex.put(current, i);
```

I thought they are exactly the same thing. What's the thing I missed causing the above if-else statement not working?

Answer (score 4):

Your ternary needs to select a `Map`, then you can call `put` on that single `Map`. You currently have two `put` calls. What you wanted was

```
((findex.get(current) == null) ? findex : lindex).put(current, i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that created another question. Why this doesn't work? int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
        
        ((a==1)? b : c)=4;

Comment: @ZephyrusK Because Java does not support that syntax. The ternary is a [*conditional operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Answer (score 1):

Your title answers the question.

It's an **expression**.  An expression is not a statement.  The two are not interchangeable in Java.

You see that the expression `a + b` is not a statement, I suppose? The same reasoning applies to the expression `a ? b : c`.   You need to "do something" with an expression to turn it into a statement - use it in an assignment, an if-statement, and so on.

(By the way, the operator is the conditional operator. Referring to it as "the operator with three operands" is kind of vague.)

Comment: This is the precise answer; the OP simply needed to assign the result of the `put` (Integer).